# Strings of infinite length?

Tags: strings, closure-properties

Suddenly a thought came to my mind and I thought of resolving it as follows.
We know that:
String is a **finite** sequence of symbols from an alphabet $\Sigma$

i.e. we cannot have an infinite sequence representing a string, which means there is no definition such as
$w = "abcabe...........$

which is unending

Now when we consider the definition of ${\Sigma}^*$, we see that the set is infinite, which implies that there could be strings having infinitely large length => which seems to sort of contradict the basic defintion of strings at a first glance.

But if we look into the matter closely then we shall see that for whatever value of length of the strings ($n$) we choose, we get a string of finite length, no matter however large $n$ is .

Is the way in which I resolved it correct or a more refined method of resolution exists?

Comment: What is ${\Sigma}^*$ and what is its definition? Which set is infinite? How is that related to strings defined as "a finite sequence of symbols from an alphabet $\Sigma$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpler example. Consider the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers:
$$
\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}.
$$
The set $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, but each number is finite.

In fact, your situation is very similar, since
$$
\Sigma^* = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \Sigma^n.
$$
Each of the sets $\Sigma^n$ is finite, yet the set $\Sigma^*$ is infinite.

Each word in each $\Sigma^n$ is finite, so each word in $\Sigma^*$ is finite.

---

Here is a related point.

Words in $\Sigma^n$ have bounded length, but the length of words in $\Sigma^*$ is unbounded. Yet the length of each word itself is finite.

Similarly, each number in $\mathbb{N}$ is finite, yet $\sup \mathbb{N} = \infty$.

---

Finally, let me say that words of infinite length are quite useful. The set $\Sigma^\omega$, known as the set of $\omega$-words, consists of all "one-way" infinite words. A word in $\Sigma^\omega$ is a mapping $w\colon \omega \to \Sigma$ ($\omega$ is another symbol for $\mathbb{N}$). We think of it as given by symbols $w_n \in \Sigma$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Two-way infinite words form $\Sigma^\zeta$, where $\zeta$ is the same as the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of all integers.

More generally, you can consider $\Sigma^\alpha$ for every linear order $\alpha$.