# Is $\Sigma^*$ countable or uncountable?

Tags: uncountability

Consider $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$. Now $\Sigma^*$ represents the collection of all possible strings over alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$.
As there exists an enumeration procedure for $\Sigma^*$, it is countably infinite. As $\Sigma^*$ consists of strings of all lengths, it also consists of strings of infinite length. Let us consider a subset $S$ of $\Sigma^*$, namely

$$ S = \{\text{Set of all strings of infinite length}\}. $$

From Cantor’s diagonalization argument, it can be proved that $S$ is uncountably infinite. But we also know that every subset of a countably infinite set is finite or countably infinite. This leads to a contradiction.

Where did the above argument go wrong?

Comment: $\Sigma^*$ does not contain infinite length strings. It contains all strings with *finite* length, however.

Comment: Adding to what @nirshahar said. If you are having problem to get the idea. Note $\Sigma^*$ is set of all possible strings of _finite_ length from our alphabet $\Sigma$. $\Sigma^*=\Sigma^0 \cup \Sigma^1 \cup \Sigma^2 ...$ Any possible string which you take from $\Sigma^*$ as per the above definition has a finite length say $n$, but this length might be very very huge, but is finite however. And the strings of _infinite_ length are a different situation after all. They do not have a finite length. $w \in S$ ($S$ defined by you) is a continuous stretch of symbols from $\Sigma$, $\notin \Sigma^n$

Comment: $\Sigma ^*$ is the set of all **finite** strings over $\Sigma$. By contrast, the set of all strings of infinite length over $\Sigma$ is sometimes referred to as $\Sigma^\omega$ or $\Sigma^{\mathbb{N}}$. As you already know, $\Sigma^*$ is countable, and as you've just discovered, $\Sigma^\omega$ is uncountable.

Comment: Similar question: [Strings of infinite length?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126390/strings-of-infinite-length)

Answer (score 2):

The argument went wrong at the point where you said that $\Sigma^*$ includes strings of infinite length. Specifically your set $S$ is an empty set. $\Sigma^*$ includes just an infinite number of strings of arbitrarily large but finite lengths.

As some commenters pointed out infinite strings are in $\Sigma^\omega$ which is uncountable.